# Creating a new Sheet with Excel vba doesnt work

Tags: excel, vba

I tried

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Tempo"
End Sub
```

but nothing happens, except that the last sheet in the workbook gets activated.

Comment: OP Comment:  _I realized that it does indeed work. however it doesn't work if I use the same code inside a function instead of a sub. What is up with that?_  It should work inside a function unless you're trying to use the function as a worksheet formula in which case it won't work (it can only return a value to the cell the function is entered in).

Answer (score 1):

```
Function createSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Tempo"
End Function
```

Do you already have a sheet that is named "Tempo"? You can't create multiple sheets with the same name, this leads to an error. The error message may be supressed by a previous `On Error` -statement.